# Blank Datas in highcharts using Codeigniter and highcharts

Tags: php, codeigniter, highcharts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82UoG.png)

[image]

im new in using codeigniter . our teacher requires us to have highcharts in our system but the chart displays like on the picture .

**my View:**

```
$(function () {
        $('#chart-A').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Reports for Most Ordered Pizza'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Ordered Pizzas Only'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'category',
                labels: {
                    rotation: -45,
                    align: 'right',
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '13px',
                        fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                    }
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Sales (Peso)'
                }
            },
            // plotOptions: {
            //     series: {
            //         minPointLength: 0
            //     }
            // },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '<b>{point.y} Pesos</b>',
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Sales',
                data: <?php echo json_encode($pizzas);?>,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    rotation: -90,
                    color: '#FFFFFF',
                    align: 'right',
                    x: 4,
                    y: 10,
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '13px',
                        fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',
                        textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                    }
                }
            }]
        });
```

**My Controller:**

```
public function tabular()
    {
        $data['pizzas'] = $this->user_model->tabular();
        var_dump($this->user_model->tabular());

        $this->load->view('template/header');
        $this->load->view('template/menubar');
        $this->load->view('template/highcharts',$data);
        $this->load->view('template/footer');

    }
```

**My Model:**

```
public function tabular() {
        $this->db->select('products.name AS name, SUM(order_details.price) AS total');
        $this->db->from('order_details');
        $this->db->join('products', 'products.prod_id = order_details.prod_id', 'LEFT');
        $this->db->group_by("products.prod_id");
        $query = $this->db->get();
        foreach ($query->result() as $row){
            $results[] = array(
                'name' => $row->name,
                'total' => (float) $row->total
            );

        }
        return $results;
    }
```

how can i fix this ? please help me .

Comment: can you paste your $pizzas json?

Comment: Paste json_encode($pizzas) here.

Comment: string '[{"name":"pizza burger","total":870},{"name":"buffalo chicken","total":1085},{"name":"bacon mushroom","total":165},{"name":"sausage mania","total":450},{"name":"beef shawarma","total":1575},{"name":"yummy hotdog","total":230},{"name":"oreo pina","total":240},{"name":"tuna garlic","total":130},{"name":"all hungarian","total":135},{"name":"beef pepperoni","total":135},{"name":"hawaiian","total":480}]' (length=401)

Comment: when i var_dump that json_encode , that is the result

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be you have miss the CSS in your chart. Reload the page again and press F12 and check the console for missing .css files. Also make sure enable errors showing in your PHP code to make sure backend code is working without any error.

Comment: this is not an answer. it's comment

Comment: bootstrap.js:8 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
    at bootstrap.js:8
bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
    at bootstrap.min.js:6

Answer (score 0):

I Guess you are missing the formation of `highchart` for which data to be passed in formatted order.
Have a look at below example

[https://www.daniweb.com/programming/web-development/threads/471751/highcharts-mysql-and-codeigniter-help]

Comment: tnx for commenting , but i cnt figure it out